# Tridion: Dreamweaver doesn't resolves the HTML code field

Tags: dreamweaver, tridion, templating, tridion-2011

We have a compound CT, which outputs the code field of one of the component.

The dream-weaver part of CT is as follows:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Component.HTMLCode" -->
    @@Component.HTMLCode@@
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

However this CT displays the code field on the page, instead of converting into HTML.

For eg: If the code field has a value as ->
 `<div align="center" id="loginapp"></div>` 
Then this same value is displayed on page instead of parsing.

In the page source, we get output as "**&lt ;div align=&quot ;center" id=&quot ;loginapp&quot ;&gt ;&lt ;/div&gt** ;"

I know this can be resolved if we use C#.
But is there any way using dreamweaver to stop the conversion of special characters?

Comment: Have you added "Default Finishing Actions TBB" in your CT as it strips XHTML from RTF content  ?

Comment: Can you specify what kind of field you are trying to output? RTF enabled or Plain Text? Thanks

Comment: Ram: I tried removing it, no success.
Chris: The field is a non-RTF multiline field. The component is properly rendered with old VBscript template. I am trying to implement the same using compound template.

Comment: This could be easily solved with xslt TBB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help. After lots of trials with dreamweaver code, we decided to use C# TBB instead which solved the purpose.

Also reading the multiline field as a textfield was one of the mistake we committed. This caused the field value to be displayed on page instead of rendering as a code behind.

We finally solved the issue using "MultilineTextField".

Comment: Hi Vikas, thanks for the help. But I did not use the workaround as my purpose was met directly by using C#.

Answer (score 6):

You should use dwt to publish the code to server, I mean create new dwt for every code and just paste the code in the dwt. you can use this dwt with emply component or resource type component.

or if you want to use text field, try following tbb code. add this tbb at the end of the template.

```
public override void Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
    {


        Regex objExp = new Regex(@"&#\d+;", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Regex objDecExp = new Regex(@"[^0-9]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        this.Initialize(engine, package);
        string strPackage = package.GetValue("Output");

        strPackage = unescapeHTML(strPackage);

        strPackage = objExp.Replace(strPackage, delegate (Match match)
        {

            string strInput = match.ToString();
            strInput = objDecExp.Replace(strInput, "");


            int intValue = Convert.ToInt32(strInput);
            char strChar = (char)intValue;

            return strChar.ToString();
        });



        strPackage = strPackage.Trim();

        Item objOutput = package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Html, strPackage);
        package.PushItem("Output", objOutput);

    }

    private string unescapeHTML(string strInput)
    {
        StringBuilder strOutput = new StringBuilder(strInput);
        strOutput.Replace("&quot;", "&#34;");
        strOutput.Replace("&nbsp;", "&#32;");
        strOutput.Replace("&amp;", "&#38;");
        strOutput.Replace("&apos;", "&#39;");
        strOutput.Replace("&lt;", "&#60;");
        strOutput.Replace("&gt;", "&#62;");
        strOutput.Replace("&iexcl;", "&#161");
        strOutput.Replace("&cent;", "&#162");
        strOutput.Replace("&pound;", "&#163");
        strOutput.Replace("&curren;", "&#164");
        strOutput.Replace("&yen;", "&#165");
        strOutput.Replace("&brvbar;", "&#166");
        strOutput.Replace("&sect;", "&#167");
        strOutput.Replace("&uml;", "&#168");
        strOutput.Replace("&copy;", "&#169");
        strOutput.Replace("&ordf;", "&#170");
        strOutput.Replace("&not;", "&#172");
        strOutput.Replace("&shy;", "&#173");
        strOutput.Replace("&reg;", "&#174");
        strOutput.Replace("&macr;", "&#175");
        strOutput.Replace("&deg;", "&#176");
        return strOutput.ToString();    
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I recall correctly it is depending on your fieldtype, if in your Schema you use a normal text field, then HTML is escaped, if you use a rich text field, it will be resolved.

An option would perhaps be to write a Dreamweaver Custom function which allows you to unescape the field (represent it as an HTML field rather than a text field). As you mentioned you could also do it in a TBB, but the Dreamweaver Custom Functions are directly callable from the DWT Template. Either way I think you indeed need to do some coding yourself.

Comment: Ok, thanks Bart. But we are using a multiline non-RTF text field. Any idea of such functions?

Comment: You will have to write your own custom function or C# TBB then. In the code of such a TBB, you can push the HTML fragment into the package with a construct like `package.PushItem(package.CreateHtmlItem(((TextField)fields["HTMLCode"]).Value)`.

Answer (score 2):

RenderComponentField has two parameters: bool htmlEncodeResult, and bool resolveHtmlAsRTFContent. Are you using this built in function?

Comment: No, I haven't this in function.

Comment: @Huston: have a look at this page for a list of all built-in functions and examples of their usage: http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/BuiltInFunctionsForUseInHtmlTemplates

Comment: Thanks Frank. I need to use this function "RenderComponentField(string fieldExpression, int fieldIndex, bool htmlEncodeResult, bool resolveHtmlAsRTFContent)"

I am not sure what does the parameter 'string fieldExpression' stands for? I tried giving the values field Name, Component.Fields.<FieldName>, but it gives error.

Comment: Normally just the field name is enough.